# SASS: meta.load-css <without selector>

Tags: sass, themes, meta

I'm trying make a module like this:

```
button, .btn {
   @include meta.load-css("theme");

   &:hover {
      @include meta.load-css("theme-hover");
   }
}
```

theme-hover.scss

```
selector {
   background-color: red;
}
```

the theme-hover.scss should not have any selector like this:

```
background-color: red;
```

but without selector the scss compiler refuses the code.
I tried using `> & { ... }` and `&:not(suck) { ... }` but none of them succeeded.

any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid this by wrapping the CSS code in `@mixin`, which will be made accessible by the `@use` and `@include` instead of the `@use "sass:meta";` and `@include meta.load-css()` rule.

```
// _module.scss
@mixin foo {
  foo: foo;
}

// main.scss
@use "module";

.bar {
  &:bar {
    @include module.foo;
  }
}

// main.css
.bar:bar {
  foo: foo;
}
```

Comment: using @ use or @ include are not dynamically changed.

my goal is make a sass lib that can be configured & customized

@use "my-button" with (
   $theme: "themes/default",
   $theme-hover: "themes/hover"
);